# Funnel plot in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

Is there a way to create a [funnel plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funnel_plot) in Python using Pandas? The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) does not seem to have something relevant.

Comment: There's a library called [pygal](http://pygal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/documentation/types/funnel.html) that seems to have something called a 'funnel plot'. Is that it?

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never.
With **plotly** you can perform funnels. Here is a simple example https://plot.ly/python/funnel-charts/

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found so far is to use **matplotlib** library along with **pandas** to create *segmented horizontal bar chart*. You will need to add one dummy category in order to shift categories to centre. Detailed explanation can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89475/how-would-you-visualize-a-segmented-funnel-and-could-you-do-it-with-python).

There's another solution if you want to use the *non-segmented bar chart* you can create the function, more details can be found [here](https://community.periscopedata.com/t/q556yj/funnel-charts-in-python).

Answer (score -2):

#I am new to Python; I figured it out, did the code below, and it worked.
#Doing a simple funnel plot with data from a csv file
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df=pd.read_csv("C:\Users\User\Desktop\file_name.csv")# path and file
df= df.sort_values('scores', ascending= False)# True or False for type of sorting
print(df.head(5))# preview data
fig = px.funnel(df['category_column'].values, df['column_with_float'].values,color='red')
fig.show()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).